# I need to sign a XML with a specific format, I have an example of what I should get but I'm not being able to replicate it

Tags: java, xml, x509certificate, xml-signature, xades

In the correct form of the file there are thee fields coming from the same .pfx certificate and ends with something like this:

```
<ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509Certificate>
    MIIHYTCCBkmgAwIBA....
    </ds:X509Certificate>
    <ds:X509Certificate>
    MIIFgzCCA2ugAwIB...
    </ds:X509Certificate>
    <ds:X509Certificate>
    MIIG2jCCBMKgAw...
    </ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
```

But with my Java code:

```
XMLSignature sig = new XMLSignature(doc, null, XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA512);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream(certificado), contraseña);
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(ks.aliases().nextElement());
sig.addKeyInfo(cert);
sig.addKeyInfo(cert.getPublicKey());
```

```
<ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509Certificate>
    MIIHYTCCBkmgAwIBA...
    </ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
```

Which it's only the first field of the three ones...

Any idea?

Comment: [`KeyStore.getCertificate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html#getCertificate(java.lang.String)) returns only the first cert in the specified entry, while usually a privatekeyentry will contain a cert _chain_ (i.e. more than one cert which are logically linked to be used for validation) and to get all of them you **use `getCertificateChain`**.